# Javascript observables: need the functionality of a switchMap but with a slight difference

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have an Rxjs observable (`stream` in the code below)that emits observables (`subjOne` and `subjTwo`). Each of the inner observables can emit their own values in any order and at any time. My task is to capture values from subjOne until subjTwo emits its first value.

```
const subjOne = new Subject();
const subjTwo = new Subject();

const stream = Observable.create(observer => {
    observer.next(subjOne);
    observer.next(subjTwo);
});

stream
    .someOperator(subj => subj)
    .subscribe(value => console.log('Value: ', value));
```

Example 1:
`subjOne` emits values 1 and 2, then `subjTwo` emits value 3, then `subjOne` emits 4.
The output should be: 1, 2, 3.

Example 2:
`subjTwo` emits 1, then `subjOne` emits 2.
The output should be 1.

switchMap doesn't fit here because it drops the values from `subjOne` as soon as `subjTwo` is emitted from `stream`. Any ideas about how to achieve that? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** In my actual case there are not only two inner observables -- `subjOne` and `subjTwo` -- but a constant stream of them, so manually hardcoding  `subjOne.takeUntil(subjTwo)` is not a viable option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
// scan to let us keep combining the previous observable
// with the next observable
source
  .scan((current, next) => {
    // takeUntil to stop current when next produces
    const currentUntil = current.takeUntil(next);
    // now merge current with next
    return currentUntil.merge(next)
  }, Rx.Observable.empty())
  // switch to the most recent version of the combined inner observables
  .switch();
```

Note this will only work correctly if the inner observables are *hot*.  If they are cold observables, it will take a bit more code to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil).

`takeUntil` listens on one stream until the second stream emits. So for your examples

```
// Emits every second
const source = Observable.timer(0, 1000);

// Emits once after 3 seconds
const canceller = Observable.timer(3000);

source
  // Takes from the source until this stream emits
  .takeUntil(canceller)
  .subscribe({
    next: x => console.log(`Value ${x}`),
    complete: () => console.log('Done')
  });
// Value 0 -> 0 seconds
// Value 1 -> 1 seconds
// Value 2 -> 2 seconds
// Done -> 3 seconds
```

Comment: My bad, I haven't mentioned that there are actually much more inner observables in my case than just two.

Comment: So how do you determine which stream is dependent on which?

Comment: It should spit out the values from any inner observable until some of the more recent inner observables (call it X) emits its first value. At this point it should ignore all future value from the older observables and only use the values from observable X. The same as described in the original question but with 1000 observables instead of just two. So if I understand your question correctly, it's the order of appearance of those inner observables that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your two subjects out and then combine them with `takeUntil` :

```
const subjOne = new Subject();
const subjTwo = new Subject();

const stream = Observable.create(observer => {
    observer.next(subjOne);
    observer.next(subjTwo);
});

const first$ = stream.take(1).flatMap(x=>x)
const second$ = stream.skip(1).take(1).flatMap(x=>x)

first$.takeUntil(second$).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Yeah but what if there are 100 observables instead of just two?